# CloseSIngleConque not an editor command - vim

Tags: vim

I have been using these dotfiles for my vim configuration among other things:

https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

I recently updated the files and some of the control-p stuff has stopped working

If I select ,b I get the following error:

> Not an editor command CloseSingleConque

If I look at the settings file for ctrl-p I see the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,b :CloseSingleConque<CR>:CtrlPBuffer<cr>
```

My vim installation does not recognise CloseSingleConque.  Does anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking all your settings from random internet strangers is not a very good idea.

`:CloseSingleConque<CR>` is in the ruby-conque plugin that is part of this "distribution". Do you have it installed? If not, you can safely remove this part of the mapping. If it's installed, that's a bug that you should report to the author.

Take this problem as an opportunity to think again about using someone else's "distribution" versus rolling your own, progressively.

Seriously, who needs 80 plugins, including two overlapping fuzzy file/buffer navigators and another which is already bundled with Vim?

Comment: I take your point.  I have moved to vim from textmate.  This seemed like a nice transitional step.

Which navigator does vim come with?

Comment: Oops! I meant "another plugin" (matchit) not "another file navigator". I've switched from TextMate as well, in 2010, and went more or less the same way except that I installed all those plugins myself because I didn't know about such "distributions". I understood my mistake one day when I logged on a remote server and I tried to use Vim there. The fail was of epic proportion and prompted me remove everything and go back to square one. A decision that pays. A lot.